# Saving input file name as a string? C

Tags: c, file, input

I read all the threads I could find and couldn't find quite the answer - so I hope this isn't seen as a duplicate.

My assignment requires reading in a file, doing some string comparison, and printing out the name of that file.

It's quite basic and the output is just the following format:

```
*File where answer was found*
**Input1.txt** < file name
```

Is there any way to save the file name as a string when I read in the file? I'm quite new at C so a lot of the answers I found (bringing it from file descriptions, etc) are wayyyyy over my head.

Thank you!

Edit - I apologize for the lack of info I was providing. I was over thinking this way to much. What I was looking for was simply:

```
char filename[] = "input1.txt";
FILE *input = fopen("input1.txt","r");
```

Comment: How do you suppose you're going to open a file to read in the first place?  You need its name, as a string.  There's no reason why you need to lose it.

Comment: If you need answer in C, again it will be the same things you read elsewhere.  What exactly you want?

Comment: look at `fopen` `fgets` `strcmp`  if you want to search files you can use `glob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, in order to open a file you'll have to pass its **name** (char *) as a parameter to fopen or open ...

so why don't you keep that string(file name) until you finish looking for the keywords and display it if you need to.

for example if you open a file like this:

`char filename[] = "file.txt";
 FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");` // opening filename for reading

// here you check if the file contains the keyword
// if it's the case you display the file name

`printf("%s",filename);`

if you're using the sys-call "open" every thing will be the same, but you will be dealing with the file descriptor instead of the file pointer.

For more information, read the manual for fopen/open.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to figure out! Thank you! I guess I was thinking too hard about it and not realizing how simple it was. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Despite your question is a little bit vague, I'd like to answer it as the following;

First of all, you are going to do these operations on a Unix-like operating system's terminal, right? Therefore, **i/o redirection** will likely be your friend. Your standard C program's entry point is something like this:

`int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     // ... 
}`

The first parameter, `argc` represents the total number of input arguments (argument count). The second parameter of the main function, `argv` represents the argument vector (or simply, an array of arguments) and allows you to input arguments from terminal's **stdin** (which is redirected to keyboard by default) that means, as executing your C program, you may input arguments externally or by using  [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) in Unix-like systems, thanks to [Douglas McIlroy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_McIlroy) who invented and insisted to put this concept in Unix as it's being developed. Therefore, in your program, you can print your argument (technically named as **option**) by entering characters from keyboard like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

on terminal:

```
$> ./program filename.txt

filename.txt
```

Actually the code sample above is just a demonstration. In reality, you shouldn't write the program in this way. At this point, I'd like to introduce you [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) functions, which are to parse command line options properly.

Now, according to your question, I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
// pseudo-code sample:
main()
{
   get_filename_to_search();
   compare_filename_with_others(); // I suppose, you're reading these names from a file
   if(filename_found == true)
     print(file_name);
   exit();
}
```

I will not write the complete C code following the logic above for you. Because this is your assignment and you need to research and do it by yourself. However, I can provide you some hints to follow. You can connect the dots by studying these functions, here's some of them: **getopt**, **fopen**, **fclose**, **fread**, **strcmp**, **printf** and **exit**. I hope, my post will be helpful for you, good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for the incredibly detailed response! I still don't quite understand everything you wrote about but will take the time to look into it and research more! Thank you again!!